# Flexicious DataGrid FlexDataGirdEvent.EDIT_END special case

Tags: events, itemrenderer, flex-datagrid, flexicious

I have a Flexicious DataGrid set up, and I have an ItemRenderer set on a certain column. Now, when I am editing an editable cell, and then stop editing it, the DataGrid fires a FlexDataGrid.EDIT_ITEM_END event (or something like that). When this is fired, I want to do a certain action. That's simple enough. The problem though, is I have a special case:

If a user is editing an editable cell and then clicks away from it (which would cause FlexDataGrid.EDIT_ITEM_END fire), but he happens to click on a button which is within the ItemRenderer set on the column, then in that case I don't want to do the action. I don't know how to make an event work like this though.

Basically I'm looking for an event that is FlexDataGrid.EDIT_ITEM_END_AND_CLICKED_ON_ANYTHING_OTHER_THAN_THAT_BUTTON and I'd like to fire that instead of FlexDataGrid.EDIT_ITEM_END. But alas, I checked the docs and that event doesn't exist =-(.

What can I do? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ITEM_EDIT_CANCEL? This has a triggerEvent which should have a target property that should tell you what display object the click happened on.